# ISV LMA - Ability Manage Experience Cloud User Seats or Logins separate to standard internal Lightning Experience users

Tags: isv, lma, packagelicense

Is it possible to manage Experience Cloud user Seats or Logins for a 2nd Generation Manage Package separate to standard internal Lightning Experience users?

Our Package is currently being licensed by seats with LMA. This makes sense for client's standard internal Lightning Experience users but not their Experience Cloud users (partners/customers):

- They'd pay the per user per month license for internal.
- but not the same price for Experience Cloud users due less usage/infrequent.

So at a minimum we'd want want to ring fence restrict licenses seats that can be granted for internal Lightning Experience users.

Salesforce community have mentioned Salesforce did some research and pilot for 'Enhanced Licensing' how mention this on hold.